# Maven in multimodule web project: how to put sibling modules output to WEB-INF/classes and not into WEB-INF/lib as JARs?

Tags: maven-2, war

I have a multi-module Maven project.
By default when I build a web module, all sibling modules of type JAR it depends on are copied to WEB-INF/lib folder. I want output of sibling modules to be placed in WEB-INF/classes folder without packaging to JAR.

More general question may be: how to keep sibling modules' configuration files out of JARs so that they can be edited after deployment easily?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), although that requires that the sibling be of type war rather than jar. There's also using the dependency plugin to unpack the jar, but it will only unpack the version in your local repository, not the one you just packaged.

As for your 'more general' question, there's the [excludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) tag for the jar plugin.

Answer (score 2):

In case if somebody is interested, I found this solution. I had exactly the same issue.

```
            <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/MYPACKAGE_TO_EXCLUDE.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack-MYPACKAGE_TO_EXCLUDE</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>MYPACKAGE_TO_EXCLUDE</artifactId>
                                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes
                                </outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: This is how I would have done it, but remember what the other guy said: "it will only unpack the version in your local repository, not the one you just packaged"

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd yes, but if I do a full rebuild, in a parent maybe with mvn install, MYPACKAGE gets built and copied to the local repo first, and then comes the build this project. or do you say that the build of the second project precedes MYPACKAGE's upload to the repo?

Comment: You sir are my hero.  Thanks for taking the time to post your solution.