# Intellij: How to add module compile output to web-inf/classes in stead of web-inf/lib?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, war, vs-web-application-project

I'm using maven to set up a war project in `IntelliJ` and run in it `GlassFish`. The war project depends on several other modules. When I run the project in debug mode, hot deploying codechanges of the changes results in `NoClassDefFound` exceptions. I found out that `IntelliJ` tries to redeploy the module jar but `GlassFish` keeps a lock on it so it fails. All the classes in that module are now unavailable, causing these `NoClassDefFound` exceptions.

`IntelliJ` generates the artifacts this way: the dependent modules are all added as jar dependencies as if they were external dependencies:

[image: img: Automatically generated artifact]

Now, when I remove the jar dependencies, `IntelliJ` tells me it found some missing dependencies and proposes a fix to add the missing dependencies.

Fixing those dependencies will add the module compile output to the `WEB-INF\classes` folder.

[image: img: dependencies in classes folder]

Once deployed, `IntelliJ` has no problem anymore hot-deploying changed classes to GlassFish since there's no jar to keep a lock on.

### Problem

Every time I make a change to any `pom.xml`, `IntelliJ` refreshes the artifacts automatically, which is fine: I definitely want to see those changes appear in the artifact. However, all modules are added as `jar` dependencies again.

### Question

How can I make sure that IntelliJ adds the compile output of project modules to `WEB-INF\classes` and not to `WEB-INF\lib`?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634943/maven-in-multimodule-web-project-how-to-put-sibling-modules-output-to-web-inf-c) but it has two problems:

1. There are many module dependencies so if possible I'd like to avoid specifying them all one by one in the unpack goal
2. `IntelliJ` seems to ignore this. When I add that configuration and while it works perfectly in a maven commandline build, `IntelliJ` still refuses to add the module compile output to the `WEB-INF\classes` dir

I found [a bugreport](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88392) that asks about the same thing but for me it's hard to believe there's no way to solve this problem. Other webapp developers using `IntelliJ` must have this same issue, making it difficult to hot-deploy code changes, unless I did something wrong in my `pom` configuration.